# Python - Excel import unorderable types empty cells

Tags: python, excel, datetime, xlrd, cells

Im trying to import data from an excel spreadsheet into an access database using Python. I have created the script but i'm having some issues with the date fields. There are currently two cols in the Excel spreadsheet that contain dates (Problem_due_date and Root_cause_identified)

It inserts the data into the table fine but it inserts the data as text

```
import pypyodbc
import xlrd
import datetime

book = xlrd.open_workbook("I:\Documents\Management\ReportAutomationProject\EMEA YTD.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Page 1")

conn = pypyodbc.connect(
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
    r"Dbq=I:\Documents\Management\ReportAutomationProject\Data.accdb;")
cur = conn.cursor()

query = """insert into Problems ([Number], Title, Active, Causing_IT_Service, Causing_Application, Causing_application_Instance, Incident_Severity, Problem_due_date, Assignment_group, Assignee, Impacted_countries, Impacted_regions, Business_impact_description, Workaround, Root_cause, Root_cause_level_3, Root_cause_level_2, Root_cause_level_1, Root_cause_identified, Causing_organisation, Problem_Summary, Activity_due, Approval_status, Major_incident, Approval_history, Approval_set, Business_duration, Duration) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""

for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    Number = sheet.cell(r, 0).value
    Title = sheet.cell(r, 1).value
    Active = sheet.cell(r, 2).value
    Causing_IT_Service = sheet.cell(r, 3).value
    Causing_Application = sheet.cell(r, 4).value
    Causing_application_Instance = sheet.cell(r, 5).value
    Incident_Severity = sheet.cell(r, 6).value
    Problem_due_date = sheet.cell(r, 7).value
    Problem_due_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(Problem_due_date, book.datemode))
    Assignment_group = sheet.cell(r, 8).value
    Assignee = sheet.cell(r, 9).value
    Impacted_countries = sheet.cell(r, 10).value
    Impacted_regions = sheet.cell(r, 11).value
    Business_impact_description = sheet.cell(r, 12).value
    Workaround = sheet.cell(r, 13).value
    Root_cause = sheet.cell(r, 14).value
    Root_cause_level_3 = sheet.cell(r, 15).value
    Root_cause_level_2 = sheet.cell(r, 16).value
    Root_cause_level_1 = sheet.cell(r, 17).value
    Root_cause_identified=sheet.cell(r, 18).value
    Root_cause_identified=datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(Root_cause_identified, book.datemode))
    Causing_organisation = sheet.cell(r, 19).value
    Problem_Summary = sheet.cell(r, 20).value
    Activity_due = sheet.cell(r, 21).value
    Approval_status = sheet.cell(r, 22).value
    Major_incident = sheet.cell(r, 23).value
    Approval_history = sheet.cell(r, 24).value
    Approval_set = sheet.cell(r, 25).value
    Business_duration = sheet.cell(r, 26).value
    Duration = sheet.cell(r, 27).value
    values = (Number, Title, Active, Causing_IT_Service, Causing_Application, Causing_application_Instance, Incident_Severity, Problem_due_date, Assignment_group, Assignee, Impacted_countries, Impacted_regions, Business_impact_description, Workaround, Root_cause, Root_cause_level_3, Root_cause_level_2, Root_cause_level_1, now, Causing_organisation, Problem_Summary, Activity_due, Approval_status, Major_incident, Approval_history, Approval_set, Business_duration, Duration)
    cur.execute(query, values)

sql = """
select * from Problems
"""
cur.execute(sql)

for results in cur:
    print(results)

cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I have tried running using the datetime.datetime with xlrd.xldate_as_tuple which seems to work however im receiving this error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/d/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/d/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    a1_as_datetime = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, book.datemode))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xldate.py", line 65, in xldate_as_tuple
    if xldate < 0.00:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()
```

I have then drilled down into whats bringing this back. When i take it out of the for loop it works fine. I have then added into just a plain print statement and i have realized its failing as soon as it hits blank cells in the excel spreadsheet.

How would I go about skipping past these cells or reformatting them?

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because you are trying to convert text ('', i.e. blank) values to dates, and that only works with numeric values.  To convert only date values (floats formatted as dates), you can use code like this:

```
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    values = [ datetime.datetime(*(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(v, book.datemode))) 
               if t == xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE 
               else v 
               for t, v in zip(sheet.row_types(r), sheet.row_values(r)) ]
    # if '' isn't acceptable for the date columns, you may need to fix them here...
    # e.g.
    # values[18] = values[18] or datetime.datetime.now()
    cur.execute(query, values)
```

You may still need to fix up `values[7]` (`Problem_due_date`) and `values[18]` (`Root_cause_identified`) if they are not datetime values.